# JMeter How to add a Test element dynamically/programmatically?

Tags: java, swing, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have the JMeter code, (https://jmeter.apache.org/svnindex.html).

In JMeter we can add testelements by right clicking on test plan>add>.... 
I want to automate this adding of a testelement (eg: Regular expression extractor) to the testplan. Means, I have a button on my HTTP request form (or any testelement). Upon clicking the button a regular expression extractor should be added in the testplan tree as a child of the HTTP request. Could you please help me?

package org.apache.jmeter.extractor.gui.RegexExtractorGui is the class for  regular expression extractor gui.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered some form of controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for my Question from AddToTree of org.apache.jmeter.gui.action package as guiPackage.getTreeModel().addComponent(testElement, parentNode);

Here, guiPackage is an instance of org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage class.

Testelement can be created using guiPackage.createTestElement(classname).

guiPackage.getCurrentNode() will provide currently selected node.

finally guiPackage.getTreeModel().addComponent(testElement, parentNode) will add the testelement as a child of parent node.

Thank u

Answer (score 0):

To safe your time you can use [JMeter template feature](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-save-%E2%80%98loads%E2%80%99-time-using-jmeters-template-feature). You can create your own templates with combination of any JMeter elements. May be it's what you are looking for?

Comment: Thank u Jay for your time. Actually I was looking for an API in the source code for adding a test element dynamically.

Comment: I got the API from AddToTree class as guiPackage.getTreeModel().addComponent(testelement, parentnode)